# Angular GET from API Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'

Tags: angular, api

I'm trying to GET data from an API and display it in my component. I can get the data successfully, as it prints in the console, but I am not able to display it on the page.

The console gives me the error: **Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.**

I have tried with JSON placeholder API, which works fine, so I am thinking it has something to do with how the data is structured in the API I'm using.

Here is my component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { RecipeService } from '../services/recipe.service';
import { Recipe } from '../models/Recipe';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-recipe',
  templateUrl: './recipe.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./recipe.component.css']
})
export class RecipeComponent implements OnInit {

  recipes: Recipe
  constructor(
    private recipeService: RecipeService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.recipeService.getRecipes().subscribe(response => {
      this.recipes = response;
      console.log(response)
    });

  }
}
```

Here is my service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

import { Recipe } from '../models/Recipe';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class RecipeService {

  constructor(private httpClient:HttpClient) { }

  apiUrl:string = 'https://www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/categories.php';

  getRecipes():Observable<Recipe> {
    return this.httpClient.get<Recipe>(`${this.apiUrl}`)
  }
}
```

And here is my HTML page:

```
<div class="container mx-auto mt-20">
    <h2 class="text-2xl">Welcome to the recipes page</h2>
    <div class="grid grid-cols-6 mt-10 recipe-grid">
        <div class="recipe" *ngFor="let recipe of recipes">
            <h4>{{recipe.title}}</h4>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

## **UPDATE**

I now changed the response so it's in an array, I think

this.recipes = response; changed to  this.recipes = [response];

This removed the previous error, but it's now saying

**Property 'strCategory' is missing in type 'Recipe[]' but required in type 'Recipe'.**

strCategory is currently the only data I have put in my recipe model

```
export class Recipe {
    strCategory: string;
}
```

How would I fix this?

Comment: The error told you that you're trying to *ngFor over an object, instead of an array.
First, you're probably getting an array, so I would suggest to initilize like this `recipes: Recipe[] = [];`. Then, could you show us what the `console.log` gives you ?

Comment: @Emilien
That was the first thing I tried, and the output is the same. I read somewhere that the API doesn't output an array, but an object, but I am not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Your service seems to return a `Recipe` Object instead of a list.

Try `return this.httpClient.get<Recipe[]>` and change your code from `Recipe` to `Recipe[]`

`*ngFor` use an array instead of an object, hence the error code

**Edit
Try this:

```
export class RecipeService {

  constructor(private httpClient:HttpClient) { }

  apiUrl:string = 'https://www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/categories.php';

  getRecipes():Observable<Recipe[]> {
    return this.httpClient.get<Recipe[]>(`${this.apiUrl}`)
  }
}
```

in the calling class:

```
    ....
    
   public recipes: Recipe[] = []
        
   public ngOnInit() {
   this.getRecipes.subscribe({
     next: result => {
       this.recipes.push(result)
     }
   });
}
```

Comment: That returns the same error, but also:
Argument of type 'Recipe[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Recipe'.